# Any example of Apache Spark org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions usage? ..drop() doesn't seem to work?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter a dataset with NA values..found  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions 
but it seems its drop() or drop("any") doesn't seem to work properly..anyone tried ..or please share usage in java ..thank you...

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions;
    Dataset<Row> inputDS=spark.read().option("header","true").
                                 csv("inputfile.csv");
    inputDS.show();

    //Updated dataset...remove null or NAN 
    DataFrameNaFunctions inputDatasetsansNullorNAN=new DataFrameNaFunctions(inputDS);
    Dataset<Row> inputDSnulldropped=inputDatasetsansNullorNAN.drop();
    inputDSnulldropped.show();
```

............
Input File

```
name item
```

1.Alice,milk
 2. Bob,null 
 3. NA,
 4. Test,a
 5. NA,NA
 6. null,NA
 7. Bob, NA
 8. 
 9.

## output

name item
1.Alice milk
2.Bob null
3.Test a
4.NA NA
5.null NA
6.Bob NA

Answer (score 1):

DataFrameNaFunctions is created from the na method of the dataframe so you should be doing something like this:

```
val withoutNulls = inputDs.na.drop()
```

Also, please note that null in a csv is achieved by having no value (e.g. 3,,4 means the column between the 3 and 4 is null). If you are using instead something like "null" string then na functions will not work. Instead you might do something like:

```
val withoutNulls = inputDs.filter(!($"columnName" === "null"))
```

Comment: Thank you.. getting DataframeNAFunctions from na and using drop worked. I tried the other snippet for values like NA or null..but not getting it  using java...  inputDS.filter(!($item=="null"))

Comment: sorry, the === is scala shorthand. Try inputDs.filter(col("columnName").notEqual("null"))